# Display an Array as a List inside a Table

Tags: theming

I have an array that have a created with items in it that I want to populate a cell in a table.  In my case this is a table of Orders in Ubercart and have created an array, called `$models` that is populated with the Model numbers of the line items in that order.  What would be the best way to display this array in my table?

Currently,

```
$rows[] = array(
  ...
  array('data' => $models),
  ...
```

display's nothing in the Model column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [`theme_item_list()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7) which

> Returns HTML for a list or nested list of items.

e.g.

```
$rows[] = array(
  ...
  array('data' => theme('item_list', array('items' => $models))),
  ...
```

Comment: thats working but it's only displaying the first item in the array and not looping through the whole array.